# Validar array de inputs que no permita procesar el formulario, con valores ingresados entre (1-4) ni mayores a 10

Tags: javascript, html5

```html
   <form method="POST" action="Capt_Calif.php" onsubmit="return valida(parcial)">
         <!-- arreglos usando class para ser llamados por js, p1=calif de parcial1  -->
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="p1" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[2]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP1[]" class="ip1" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[3]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="p2" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[4]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP2[]" class="ip2" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[5]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="p3" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[8]; ?>" ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="parcialP3[]" class="ip3" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[9]; ?>" ></td>

          <td><input type="hidden" name="idgpo[]" value="<?php echo $alumno[10]; ?>" readonly></td>
          <td><input type="hidden" name="idalumno[]" value="<?php echo $alumno[7]; ?>" readonly></td>
     
          <td><input type="text" name="final[]" class="final" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[11]; ?>" readonly ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="porcent[]" class="final" size="3" value="<?php echo $alumno[12]; ?>" readonly ></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="asistotales[]" class="inatot" size="3" value="" ></td>
</form>
```

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function valida(parcial) {
  var i,
  inputs,
  inputsTotal,
  inputsIndex;

  for (i=0; i < parcial; i++) {
  inputs = document.getElementsByClassName(parcial[i]);
  var n = inputs.length;
  inputsIndex = 0;
  inputsTotal = inputs.length;

  for(inputsIndex; inputsIndex < inputsTotal; inputsIndex++) {
  p1 = inputs[i];
  p2 = inputs[i];
  p3 = inputs[i];
     //////////////////////////////////////// PARA ARREGLO PARCIAL2
     if (p1 = 4 || p1 = 3)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p1 = 2 || p1 = 1)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p1 > 10)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
    //////////////////////////////////////// PARA ARREGLO PARCIAL1
     if (p2 = 4 || p2 = 3)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p2 = 2 || p2 = 1)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p2 > 10)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     //////////////////////////////////////// PARA ARREGLO PARCIAL3
     if (p3 = 4 || p3 = 3)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p3 = 2 || p3 = 1)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }
     if (p3 > 10)  {
        alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        return false;
     }

    }//segundo for
   }//primer for
 }
</script>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
window.onload = function() { //este metodo esta, mal, algo falta
parcial(['p1', 'p2', 'p3']);
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco más tu código? ¿Lo que hace? ¿Lo que tendría que sacar?

Comment: el script js obtiene los ids de los arrays de inputs por class, no esta bien el codigo quizas en parte donde abre el segundo script, no se bien como deban ser las validaciones en arrays de inputs. 
Intentaba validar que si en cualquier  input  de ese array de inputs se introduce un numero entre (1-4) o mayor a 10 no deje procesar el formulario.

Comment: Añade esta información a la pregunta. De esta manera, usuarios que vengan a ayudarte pueden ver de una mejor manera el problema que tienes. Tendrías que poner los datos que introduces y los datos de salida para poder comprobar el script completamente. Aunque ya se ve que los datos de entrada se pueden intuir. Un saludo :)

Comment: saludos.........

Comment: por que no hacer un each por cada arreglo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vi que ademas de ocupar mal los signos `=` que es asignacion cuando deberia ser `==` para comparar los valores. Haces muchos `if` para un mismo error siendo que tu en los comentarios dijiste *numero entre (1-4) o mayor a 10* ya sabes la condición adecuada. Segundo, es mas fácil recorrer arreglo por arreglo que hacer tanto codigo para algo que se puede solucionar con una variable `flag`

Dejo una tabla ordinaria para este ejemplo :

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="parcialP1[]" size="3" type="text" class="evaluacion">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="parcialP1[]" size="3" type="text" class="inasistencia">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="parcialP2[]" size="3" type="text" class="evaluacion">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="parcialP2[]" size="3" type="text" class="inasistencia">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
```

En el codigo `JS` asumo que se hace click para hacer el post del formulario, creo una variable `flag` llamada `error` e inicializada en `false`. Hago un `each` arreglo por arreglo y comparo su valor

**EDIT**

Como ahora explicaste que los `inputs` de un `array` son distintos y solo quieres evaluar 1 en particular, voy a agregar a los inputs una clase, clase `evaluacion` y `inasistencia`.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#enviar").click(function() {
        var error = false;
        $('input[name^="parcialP1"]').each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('class') == "evaluacion"){
                var valor = $(this).val();
                if (valor < 5 || valor > 10 ) {
                    error = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        $('input[name^="parcialP2"]').each(function() {
            if($(this).attr('class') == "evaluacion"){
                var valor = $(this).val();
                if (valor < 5 || valor > 10) {
                    error = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
        if(error){
           e.preventDefault();
           alert('Escala Incorrecta: Ingrese Evaluación entre: 5 - 10');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Si en cada array de inputs, que son de una sola dimensión cada uno, lleva 2 datos diferentes:(evaluación e inasistencias) por periodo. Y solo necesito validar los indices que pertenecen a evaluación: 
arreglo[0] = 8; //evaluación / arreglo [1] = 1; //inasistencias.
¿Que conviene mas mandar evaluacion e inasistencias en arreglos separados? O un ciclo en el script de js, que recorra las posiciones:
Ej: var valor  = parcialP1[i - 1];

Comment: Lo que me parece es que deberias mandar arreglos distintos, son inputs distintos con distintos valores, si es que enviaras los dos valores tendrias que tener la manera de identificar que valor del arreglo corresponde a el dato que quieres evaluar.  Tu quieres que en el input la persona pueda agregar dos valores??

Comment: No, por eso hay dos <inputs> por cada periodo: en un input se ingresa evaluación, en otro numero de inasistencias, pero en la propiedad name 2 inputs tienen el mismo name="parcialP1[]", por que en el archivo php se recibe como un solo arreglo, Y cuando en PHP quiero obtener algu dato, hago esto: 
Iniciando el bucle en = 1
 $p1 = $parcialP1[$i - 1];   $inasisP1  = $parcialP1[$i]; 
 Siendo en arreglo $parcialP1[0] = 8 //evaluacion P1 y $parcialP1[1] = 1 //inasistencias P1.
¿Como puedo hacer algo asi para el script de js, para que vaya recorriendo posisiones?

Comment: Cuales son los rangos para evaluar inasistencias y para evaluacion? o son los mismos pero quieres identificar cuando uno es inasistencia y cuando uno es evaluacion?

Comment: nadamas validar que las evaluaciones que se van insertando en array, que no permita capturar de (1-4) ni mayores a 10. Las inasistencias seran sin validar. solo se valida evaluaciones. Pensaba ir recorriendo las posisiones del array para ir sacando los indices que son evaluacion, como lo que puse de php. Pero no se como ponerlo

Comment: actualizado! @ArmandoArellano

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48195/discussion-between-armando-arellano-and-sioesi).

Answer (score 0):

Por empezar, debes cambiar `parcial` por `parcial.length` en el primer `for`. ¿Para qué usas `n` si ya tienes `inputsTotal`?  Tienes que acceder a los valores de cada `input` usando la propiedad `value`, no puedes accederlos directamente: `pn = inputs[i].value`. Por último estás haciendo asignaciones donde debes hacer comparaciones, debes cambiar `pn = x`, por `pn == x` en todos los `if`.

Comment: tiene razon muchas gracias